# How to save a UIImageView to a CoreData Database

Tags: core-data, uiimageview, uiimage, nsdata

What is the **SIMPLEST** way to save a `UIImageView` to a CoreData Database. I have tried this:

**Save:**

```
 UIImage *image = imageView.image;
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [newContact setValue:imageData forKey:@"imageViewFinal"];
```

**Retrive:**

```
  imageView.image = [matches valueForKey:@"imageViewFinal"];
```

and I have added an `Attribute` called 'imageViewFinal' with a `Binary Data` type.

**PROBLEM**:

When I go to build it and click the save button, the app crashes, what's the problem?

Thanks, Seb.

Comment: Could you share the crash log? I think you should use the transformable data type to store the NSImage directly into Core Data.

Comment: brad (@bradlarson) as already pointed out it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908910/how-should-i-store-uiimages-within-my-core-data-database

Comment: Crash Log: 2012-12-23 12:26:21.783 OH&S TUE[24213:c07] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134100 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134100.)" UserInfo=0x777b5e0 {metadata={
   NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        SWMS = <bee510d9 26b795bf b82dff10 d406c2d9 ed9a13bf 084ea120 6240943c 4abeac26>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3; NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "1902A7D8-37E9-493F-8586-A76F5642AF79";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2;

Comment: }, reason=The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to create the store}, {
    metadata =     {
        NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
        NSStoreModelVersionHashes =         {
            SWMS = <bee510d9 26b795bf b82dff10 d406c2d9 ed9a13bf 084ea120 6240943c 4abeac26>;
        };
        NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
        NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =         (
            ""
        );
        NSStoreType = SQLite;

Comment: Your problem is that you changed your model file after installing the app. Core Data then doesn't know how to modify the database to take into account the changes. The simplest solution is just to delete the app from the Simulator or device and reinstall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @ShermanLo said is right, the crash log shows that you've modified your model but did not   handle the conflict between the old & new store model versions in the right way.

So just delete your App in your device/simulator, and rebuild/run it.

**Note**: Whenever you've modified your models, you need to do it this way unless you offer an approach to handle. There're many related QAs on SO. :)

Comment: @Seb yep, it's okay, but better to use `NSValueTransformer`. :)