# Why am I able to access all of the attributes from Core Data except the image attribute? (Which is binary data?)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsdata, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I do the following in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
Post *post = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Anywhere I then try to use `post.image` it says that the image property doesn't exist. But I can do `post.title` very easily. I've performed a "Clean" and a "Clean Build Folder" and restarted Xcode.

`image` is definitely in the Core Data `xcdatamodeld` file and this is the information when I select it:

[image]

Why am I unable to access it?

Comment: Is there an `@property` for `image` declared in the header file for the `Post` class?

Comment: Might be better to use a Transformable type and set the property to UIImage in the NSManagedObject subclass (see @mundi's answer below), then you get automatic conversion to/from UIImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this is in your `Post.h`:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage * image;
```

and your `Post.m`

```
@dynamic image;
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909082/427083) for convenient automatic conversions.