# How would I be best off storing images to be used as a UIImage in a Core Data store? Transformable? Binary data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uiimage, nsdata

There seems to be conflicting answers on this question and I'm confused what the best way to store images in a Core Data database is.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908910/how-should-i-store-uiimages-within-my-core-data-database) says transformable, however [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16685812/how-to-store-an-image-in-core-data) says to use Binary Data.

If I just want to take it and turn it into a `UIImage`/`UIImageView` what would I be better off using?

Comment: Both ways it's just stored as NSData in the database.  If you use a Transformable then the conversion to and from UIImage is automatic if you define the attribute in your NSManagedObject subclass as UIImage.  Transformable will work with other types as well, such as NSAttributedString.  Just be aware that if you plan on accessing these images in the database on the OS X platform you should store them as PNG or some format supported on both platforms.

Comment: Forgot to mention you need to set the Transformable name to NSKeyedUnarchiveFromDataTransformerName in the Core Data model editor to use the Apple provided transformer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally store images outside of Core Data (in the documents directory, or in the bundle) and then save paths to them in Core Data.

The other approach I've seen recommended is to save your images as BLOBs, but in a separate entity so you don't bog down your other entities with all that data.

Comment: Well, I'll be saving less than 50 and the images are thumbnails, so I don't think I have to worry about storying them outside of the main store.

Comment: @DougSmith: if it is less than 50 and they are thumbnails, I would use transformable.

Comment: I always store images outside of the database, and instead just store the URL where it is stored.

Comment: BinaryData provides the option to "allow external storage," where Transformable does not. Does that mean Transformable is always stored in the database?

Answer (score 2):

Transformable and binary are really the same thing. In both cases you're saving binary data, the difference is where the data is converted between a `UIImage` and `NSData`.

- If you use a transformable attribute, you'll use an `NSValueTransformer` to convert between the two. Your code can read and write `UIImage` directly, and the value transformer converts the format. Apple includes a sample value transformer for this purpose in one of their sample apps.
- If you use a binary attribute, you have to convert to/from `NSData` any time you access the attribute. You'd do the same steps as the value transformer, but you'd do it a different place. You'd be reading and writing `NSData` on your objects.

Either one works. A value transformer is nice because it keeps the conversion in one place, regardless of how many places your code uses the images. But either is fine, so do whatever seems most convenient.