# In Xcode 6 beta 4 (iOS 8), why does Core Data not persist UIImage fields to the backend like it did in iOS 7 when I declare it Transformable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode6

In my iOS project's data model, I have an entity called `Foo` that has a field `image`.
I've always stored this field by using the `Transformable` setting such that iOS would automatically use `NSCoding` to store image.

However, I found that when I try to retrieve it, the `UIImage *` that comes out is corrupt. It has `CGSizeZero` size most of the time and does not contain valid data.

Has anyone also experienced this under Xcode 6 beta 4?

**NB:** I'm using MagicalRecord to set up the Core Data stack. I have used the so-called 'auto-migrating' Core Data stack. I `Reset Content and Settings` every time I run this test on the simulator.

I have also tried to reproduce the issue on an in-memory data store (such that it's amenable to unit testing) but I cannot accurately reproduce the issue (because I haven't been able to teardown the stack and initialize it again).

[image]

Comment: My first suggestion would be to try it in beta 5.

Comment: WHATTTTTTTT is it out already

Comment: Released on Monday :)

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug (regression).

Comment: There's no reason this **should** be different, so if it is, it's a bug in Xcode and/or in iOS. It might be useful to look at the data that gets returned and see if it's recognizable (you mention that it's not valid, but what is it? Probably garbage but you never know until you look).

Comment: Hmmm. Okay, I've just upgraded to Xcode 6 and the behaviour is the same.

I'll try to look at the content of the images read... I presume it is just garbage but as you say, it might not be the case.

Comment: It appears that Core Data's mechanism is no longer working because UIImage changed from complying to NSSecureCoding to complying with NSCoding. The process is no longer automatically reversible for some reason.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it turns out that in iOS 8, `UIImage` now conforms to `NSSecureCoding` instead of the normal `NSCoding`. I suspect it's the change of underlying implementation that's causing the setting of `Transformable` in our data model not to work as before.

The solution is just to take the transformation in our own hands. One such way to do this is to write our own transformer, [outlined in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3909082/590767).

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer. Although UIImage now conforms to NSSecureCoding, NSSecureCoding conforms to NSCoding (and since these are just protocols, it's just requiring the UIImage class to conform to an additional method).

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this with iOS 8, after having my app work fine with iOS 7.  My problem was that I was trying to set image properties on multiple NSManagedObjects by referencing a single source image in my bundle directly; the solution is to set the properties to copies of the source image.

Details: My app lets users set an image property of players (NSManagedObjects) on a team.  The image property, of course, is a transformable attribute.  The user can either capture a photo or choose an avatar, which is saved as a .jpeg in my bundle.  For the avatar, I was setting the property with

```
player.photo = [UIImage imageNamed@"avatar.jpg"];
```

Multiple players often had the same avatar.  This wasn't a problem with iOS 7 at all, and even worked with iOS 8 as long as all the objects were in memory. But with iOS 8, the avatar images would not persist to core data after the app terminated; upon re-launch, all the images were zero-length and displayed blank space (sounds a lot like the behavior you are seeing).

The fix was to set the property to a *copy* of the source image with the following:

```
UIImage *avatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.jpg"];
player.photo = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:avatar.CGImage];
```

I can see why manually performing the transformation would *appear* to be the solution, because you'd be setting a unique object to each image property... but the real fix (in my case, at least) was much easier.